# Format for DateTimeField

Tags: python, django

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Converting string into datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466345/converting-string-into-datetime)

In Django I get this error "Enter a valid date/time in YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM[:ss[.uuuuuu]] format." when I try to assign a string "22-DEC-2009" to a DateTimeField in a **model**.

How is it possible to make DateTimeField accept a date string in format "22-DEC-2009"?

Answer (score 9):

You can pass the input formats as `input_formats` argument to `DateTimeField`, so you can do this

```
# you can keep a list of formats yourself, or copy from django 1.2 version e.g.
# my_formats = fields.DEFAULT_DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS + ['%d-%b-%Y']
# for latest django use this
from django.utils.formats import get_format
my_formats = get_format('DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS')
field = DateTimeField(input_formats=my_formats,...)
```

If instead you directly want to assign a date-str to `models.DateTimeField` best way is to just convert it to `datetime` before hand e.g.

```
mymodel.date_of_birth = datetime.datetime.strptime("22-DEC-2009", "%d-%b-%Y")
```

Comment: Isn't accepting argument input_formats for models.DateTimeField.

Comment: @Vishal , what does it say? what version are you using?

Comment: @Anurag
Error: "/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 459, in __init__
    Field.__init__(self, verbose_name, name, **kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'input_formats'"
Django version: "1.1.1"

/django/db/models/fields doesn't contain DEFAULT_DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS but /django/forms/fields.py does (which makes the code run)

Useful post:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/466345/converting-string-into-datetime

Comment: yes form.fields has it not db

Comment: input_formats is not supported in django 1.4

Comment: @hobs in that case copy the formats from old version or use new method ( edited answer)

Comment: @Anurag, thanks for providing a working `formats` import for 1.4, however the argument `input_formats` is not support for django 1.4 DateTimeFields

Comment: @hobs what do you mean by not supported? `In [2]: from django.forms.fields import DateTimeField

In [3]: DateTimeField(input_formats=[])
Out[3]: <django.forms.fields.DateTimeField at 0x2c70390>

In [4]: import django

In [5]: django.VERSION
Out[5]: (1, 4, 0, 'final', 0)
`

Comment: @Anurag, op was asking about a `models.DateTimeField`, not `forms.DateTimeField`.  `In [1]: from django.db.models import DateTimeField` 
`In [2]: DateTimeField(input_formats=[])` `TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'input_formats'`

Comment: @hobs that was already known, see my dec 09 comment, for UI forms.DateTimeField is enough if OP wants to  directly assign to model he can easily convert the date-str (see edit)

Comment: @Anurag, yea, guess I missed that.