# Strange behaviour when filtering datetime range with Django ORM

Tags: python, django, orm, sqlite

I am trying to query data from a sqlite database using Django.

**The model**

```
class SolarEntryHour(models.Model):
    time = models.DateTimeField()
    device = models.ForeignKey(Device)
    lW = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=3)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (("time", "device"))
```

**How I am trying to access the data**

```
start = datetime.datetime.utcnow()+relativedelta(hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)
end = datetime.datetime.utcnow()

ticks = SolarEntryHour.objects.filter(
    time__range=(start, end), 
    device = str(deviceID)
)
```

**Whats happening**

```
Exception Value:    
list index out of range
Exception Location: /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/util.py in typecast_timestamp, line 97
```

The exception seems to occur, when the query is actually executed (on iterating "ticks")
The query Django tries to execute, and the output of `print start; print end` looks fine

```
2013-01-01 00:00:00 - 2013-01-01 20:47:24.245942

SELECT "charts_solarentryhour"."id", "charts_solarentryhour"."time", "charts_solarentryhour"."device_id", "charts_solarentryhour"."lW" 
FROM "charts_solarentryhour" 
WHERE ("charts_solarentryhour"."device_id" = 1  AND "charts_solarentryhour"."time" 
BETWEEN 2013-01-01 00:00:00 and 2013-01-01 20:47:24.245942)
```

***EDIT:***
I think I located the problem, but **I don't know if this is expected behaviour or a Django Bug.**

The "time" field of the table "charts_solarentryhour" is defined as:
`time = models.DateTimeField()`
This table is populated by a database trigger, not entering the full datetime to this field, soley `strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H', 'now')`

When Django then executes the query, it fails when parsing the query result, since there are no minutes and seconds in the string returned from the database (thats why the list index out of range exception is being thrown)

Is it a bad practice not populating the whole datetime field?
Shouldn't Django be able to add some zeroes?
Is there any nice way to fix this without falling back to raw query execution?

Comment: can you show *how* you're iterating on ticks?

Comment: What do you mean, seems to occur? You have the traceback. What is line 97?

Comment: The code in line 97 hasn't been written by me and is django specific.

The error occurs when doing:

`for tick in ticks:`

Answer (score 0):

Q: Is it a bad practice not populating the whole datetime field?

Yes - there are lots of tools out there which will happily parse a well-formed standard date format. So when you invent your own format expect bad things to happen. Django and virtually all frameworks will expect you to use established conventions with standard field types.

Q: Shouldn't Django be able to add some zeroes?

No - this would be dark magic. "2013-01-10 10" has no conventional meaning.

Q: Is there any nice way to fix this without falling back to raw query execution?

Yes - See the answer here: [Format for DateTimeField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1945239/format-for-datetimefield)

Answer (score 0):

It is not a problem of Django
Is a strange behaviour of dateutil's relativedelta function

You had to write the following:

> > > start = datetime.datetime.utcnow()+relativedelta(hours=0,minutes=0,seconds=0,microseconds=0)

and not

> start = datetime.datetime.utcnow()+relativedelta(hour=0,minute=0,second=0,microsecond=0)

hour change replace (and so not add it to) the value of the initial one

```
>>>import datetime
>>>from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
>>>t1 = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
>>>t1 
datetime.datetime(2013, 11, 20, 18, 55, 11, 895897)
>>>t2 = t1 + relativedelta(hour=1, minute=3, second=7, microsecond=1) 
>>>t2
datetime.datetime(2013, 11, 20, 1, 3, 7, 1)
>>>t3 = t1 + relativedelta(hours=1, minutes=1, seconds=1, microseconds=1) 
>>>t3
datetime.datetime(2013, 11, 20, 19, 56, 12, 895898)
```